# Trouble understanding how props are accessed in HOC

Tags: reactjs, wrapper, react-props, high-order-component

I'm trying to understand this basic example of HOC :

```
function ppHOC(WrappedComponent) {

 return class PP extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        name: ''
      }

    this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this)
 }

 onNameChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    name: event.target.value
  })
 }

 render() {
  const newProps = {
    name: {
      value: this.state.name,
      onChange: this.onNameChange
    }
  }
  return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...newProps}/>
 }
}
```

What bugs me is the use of this.props in the return statement :

```
return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...newProps}/>
```

From what I understand "this" refers to the instance of PP ? So we are instanciating WrappedComponent with the props of PP which are the props of React.Component, am I right ? I do undersatand that we also add newProps to these props but I just don't get what we are doing with this.props here.

Also the constructor of PP is getting some props as parameters. How is PP instanciated exactly ? ppHOC(MyComponent) returns the class PP not really an instance of it right ? In order to instanciate PP you would have to do something like "ppHOC(MyComponent)(someProps)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understand "this" refers to the instance of PP ?

Yes it's correct

> So we are instanciating WrappedComponent with the props of PP which are the props of React.Component, am I right ?

Almost there, think of it this way, this is your react structure before HOC:

`` Parent component passes `props` to Child component ``

Now you wrap your Child with a HOC (`ppHOC(Child)`)
Your structure become:

`` Parent component passes `props` to the component returned from `ppHOC(Child)`, which is class PP ``

> Also the constructor of PP is getting some props as parameters. How is PP instanciated exactly ? ppHOC(MyComponent) returns the class PP not really an instance of it right ? In order to instanciate PP you would have to do something like "ppHOC(MyComponent)(someProps)" ?

It's true that `ppHOC(MyComponent) returns the class PP`, it will be initiated (rendered) by React when you start using it `<MyComponentHOC some="prop" />`.

PP is now initiated, `{ some: "prop" }` will be passed in PP's `constructor(props)` then in turn pass in to your WrappedComponent by (`...this.props`)

**In short**, `{...this.props}` is to pass through whatever props it (the HOC) received to the wrapped component

Comment: Thank you for the details. That answers pretty well all the question I had.